# Joining a table to itself

Tags: mysql

How do I join this table to itself to check if two users have both accepted a friend request?

```
mysql> select * from friendships;
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | friend_id | accepted |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |         2 |        1 |
|       2 |         1 |        0 |
|       3 |         1 |        1 |
|       1 |         3 |        1 |
|       1 |         4 |        1 |
|       4 |         1 |        0 |
|       5 |         1 |        1 |
|       1 |         5 |        0 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And also pull the user object out.

I can check if `user 1` has any outstanding friend requests;

```
mysql> select * from friendships join users on friendships.friend_id = users.id where friendships.user_id = 1 and accepted = false;
+---------+-----------+----------+----+------------+----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| user_id | friend_id | accepted | id | fullName   | username | phone              | verificationCode | accountVerified |
+---------+-----------+----------+----+------------+----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|       1 |         5 |        0 |  5 | Tom Tester | tom      | +16502222222222222 | 4444             |               1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----+------------+----------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But how do I get his accepted requests (i.e. `user 1` and `user 3` both have accepted the request)?

Also I've got a user table set up in the background.

EDIT: My schema if it helps

```
CREATE TABLE friendships (
    user_id int,
    friend_id int,
    accepted boolean not null default false,
    UNIQUE KEY friend (user_id, friend_id)
);
```

Comment: You need to have a primary key for your table to make joins work as expected which is missing in your table

Comment: AFAIK that's the standard schema for friendship tables.

Comment: You can join with self if you use alias for the table. Something like this: SELECT * FROM friendships JOIN friendships AS reverse ON reverse.friend_id = friendships.user_id

Comment: Start with smaller steps - how do you usually join two tables? You don't have to have a PK in your table, but it's more than desirable that you do. This way, MySQL will create a hidden primary key. What sucks is that you can't use it.

Comment: usually I do something like `select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id` or if I want to compare them I do `select * from table t1, table t2` and go around comparing them like they were variables.

Comment: @N.B. a combination of user_id and friend_id fields do serve as a primary key in the above table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the combination of `user_id` and `friend_id` fields serve as the primary key of your friendship table, these are the 2 fields you need to join the table on itself. Obviously, in the join criteria you have to cross reference the 2 fields, since the roles are reversed in the 2 records.

```
select *
from friendships f1
inner join friendships f2 on f1.user_id=f2.friend_id and f1.friend_id=f2.user_id
 where f1.accepted=1 and f2.accepted=a1 and f1.user_id=...
```

You can also achieve the same output by using an `exists`subquery:

```
select * from friendships f1
where f1.user_id=... and f1.accepted=1
    and exists (select 1 from friendships f2
                where f2.user_id=f1.friend_id and f1.friend_id=f1.user_id and f2.accepted=1)
```

Comment: You're a god. I was super confused on what I was meant to be doing - I've only ever worked with tables that are compared through other tables, never compared the same table to itself. Thanks dude! Also in your first example `f2.accepted=a1` should be `f2.accepted=1` or `=true` - there's an extra `a` character. <3

Comment: also for completions sake there should be a `join users on f1.friend_id=users.id` right at the front, which solves the 'pull the user object out' part of the question :D